# Model smooth transition between edge loops

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to produce a smooth connection between edge loops that can be beveled without artifacts. "Edge/Bridge Edge Loops" doesn't produce good results. Is there a way to bridge these two forms that produces good topology? Attaching the source file for anyone who has any ideas.

[image]

Source blend file here:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I think you are on the right track, maybe you need to tweak the settings and change the way of selection a little bit to get the desired result.

1. In Edit Mode select the top Edge Loop of the handle by pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd>.
2. Press <kbd>S</kbd>, <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>0</kbd> to make it flat and avoid unwanted stretching artifacts
3. <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>3</kbd> to enable face selection and select the desired region of faces
4. <kbd>RMB</kbd> > Bridge Edge Loops
5. Tick the box in Bridge Edge Loops dialoge to the bottom left across Merge setting
6. Set Merge Factor value to 1.0
7. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>, <kbd>LMB</kbd>,<kbd>RMB</kbd> to add some Loop Cuts and give this part a nice topology transition

[image]

Comment: nice +1. i like your solution. but when i tried it and added a bevel modifier i get this weird topology https://pasteboard.co/YIhFT5CPOmJQ.png any ideas?

Comment: @HarryMcKenzie try to change the Limit Angle value >30